# How to get current user data like name and email from firebase realtime databse for one user to Text Field in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to create a profile screen to get user data from firebase's real-time database like name, email, and phone number. I tried to search on google but all the examples I found are to get data from the Firestore database, not the real-time database. I would appreciate it if somebody helps me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```dart
    Future<String> getUsername() async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    User cuser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    return ref.child('User_data').child(cuser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      final String userName = snap.value['name'].toString();
      print(userName);
      return userName;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's just printing the user's Name on the terminal. How to get the Name to the text field?do you have any tutorials so I can figure out the process?

Comment: Yeah you will have tell the field from which you want to fetch the name. For better understanding you can watch this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvvBxTUAZ78

Comment: Hello brother, I saw the video but, it is working with a list view. But, I want to retrieve the user's data like name and email to a container with two texts, not all users' data. So if you have a profile screen code example, it will be great.